# http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So I've been following a tutorial for ReactJS, and when I npm start the application, I receive a response that looks like this:

````
http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from /Users/treyherman/Desktop/reactjsprogram
Hash: c3b33e153f056156a626
Version: webpack 1.13.1```
````

When I cut and paste `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/` into my browser, I can only access the IndexRoute and not any of the other routes.  In the tutorial, the instructor has a url that looks like this:

`localhost:8080/#/?_k=8bkxfe`

Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: I think you should share your webpack config file, the link to the tutorial you follow and why not put your project on github for efficient help :)

Comment: yep, share your webpack.config.js

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an IPV4/IPV6 issue. Webpack-dev-server is using IPV4 and newer laptops and browsers are using IPV6.

You have 2 options:

- try accessing that same url using your local IP 127.0.0.1
  (instead of localhost)
- use "--host ::" option, i.e.:

  ```
  "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
      "dev"  : "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.js --host ::"
  },
  ```

See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/676

I spent a few hours tackling this. Thanks to https://github.com/dragon3

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/bundle to see changes after running webpack-dev-server.

I got that path from the webpack site documentation here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#development-server.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles across this, it might be to do with having the `inline` mode set to false in `webpack.config.js`. Instead try:

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    devServer: {
        // ...
        inline: true
    }
}
```

Or run `webpack-dev-server` with the `--inline` option.